# XPATH problem with dom4j

Tags: xpath, dom4j

I am using dom4j to overwrite a value in the XML.
The XML looks like this:

```
<start>
    <name color="blue" time="555555">
        <element1 param="1">
            <value>value1</value>
            <value>value2</value>
            <value>value3</value>
        <element1>
    </name>

    <name color="blue" time="888888">
        <element2 param="1">
            <value>value1</value>
            <value>value2</value>
            <value>value3</value>
        <element1>
    </name>
</start>
```

I am trying to semect nodes by:

```
List list= document.selectNodes("//element1[@timetime='555555']" );
```

but the list returns `null`.
I wanted to change all the 3 values where `time="555555"`.

Isn't there a way to directly go to that node.

please help.

Comment: I take it that `@timetime` is a typo?

Answer (score 4):

to select the three values, use:

```
//name[@time='555555']/element1/value
```

If that returns null as well, there may be a default namespace involved and that means you need to show your entire XML.

XPath is flexible, if you want you can express the same like this:

```
//value[ancestor::name[1]/@time='555555']
```

Comment: //name[@time='555555']/element1/value is returning null. please help

Comment: "//element1/@time" works but I wanted to go directly to that node.

Comment: @user234194: You might want to post your actual XML. I mean copy-paste varbatim, because apparently you have made up your sample, and wrongly at that.

Answer (score 1):

The XPath that you are using is looking for a time attribute equal to 555555 **on element1**. However, your time attributes are on the **name** nodes.

You could go either the way Tomalak suggested, or change it to:

```
//element1[../@time='555555']
```

This is looking for an element1 node with a **parent** who has a time attribute equal to 555555.

Comment: I see that you have updated your XML, but it's currently invalid-- the element1 node needs to be closed, and the element2 node needs a closing element2 node instead of an opening element1 node. The XPath I posted works if I fix those issues. I suggest making sure that the XML you're using is valid, and then start by trying to select the root node and looking at the results, then selecting a child of the root node and looking at the results, etc until you have what you are trying to select.