# XPath to return nodes

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XPATH problem with dom4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463056/xpath-problem-with-dom4j)

I am using dom4j to overwrite a value in the XML. The XML looks like this:

```
<name color="blue" time="555555"> 
    <element1 param="1"> 
        <value>value1</value> 
        <value>value2</value> 
        <value>value3</value> 
    <element1> 
</name> 

<name color="blue" time="888888"> 
    <element2 param="1"> 
        <value>value1</value> 
        <value>value2</value> 
        <value>value3</value> 
    <element1> 
</name>
```

I am trying to select nodes by:

```
SAXReader saxReader = new SAXReader();
Document document =  saxReader.read(xmlLocation);
List list= document.selectNodes("//element1/@color/[@time='555555']" );
```

but the list returns boolean(which is true in this case). I wanted to change all the 3 values where time="555555".

If I do:

```
List list= document.selectNodes("//element1/@time" );
```

It returns nodes.(attributes and elements)
Isn't there a way to directly go to that node where time is 555555.
please help.

Comment: read both questions properly and comment it again.I know what is duplicate question means.

Comment: your xml is flawed.. you do not close `element1` nor `element2`

Comment: The input XML you showed is not well-formed (multiple top-level elements), so you should not even be able to get it parsed in order to get a result from selectNodes(). The first XPath you showed has a syntax error, and so could not return a boolean value. If you want to select the node whose time attribute has a value of 555555, use `"//*[@time = '555555']"`. This will be a `<name>` element.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the question, but shouldn't it be `//name[@time = '555555']/*/value` ? `//element1/@color/[@time='555555']` is invalid, I think.

Comment: your xpath is also malformed. can you provide a little more on what you're attempting?  Are you trying to find element1 nodes that have a color attribute and a time attribute that is equal to 555555?

Comment: Lets assume that the XML is in correct syntax. My question is when ever i use @time='555555', list returns boolean value. if I use "element1/@time" , it returns list of elements/attributes.

Comment: Your questions show that you definitely need to read a good book on XPath to grasp at least the fundamentals. Sporadic questions at forums aren't going to help.

Comment: @khachik, if you were asking about my XPath expression, I was answering the question "Isn't there a way to directly go to that node where time is 555555". One of multiple q's the OP asked.

Comment: @user234194: `My question is when ever i use @time='555555', list returns boolean value. if I use "element1/@time" , it returns list of elements/attributes.` That's not a question. Also what do you mean list returns boolean value? list is a variable of type List. It cannot return anything, and its value is of type List. Show us what it is that convinces you that the value it holds is a boolean.

Comment: -1 for posting inaccurate data and code that makes helping 10x more complicated, unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following well-formed document:

```
<names>
    <name color="blue" time="555555"> 
        <element1 param="1"> 
            <value>value1</value> 
            <value>value2</value> 
            <value>value3</value> 
        </element1> 
    </name> 
    <name color="blue" time="888888"> 
        <element1 param="1"> 
            <value>value1</value> 
            <value>value2</value> 
            <value>value3</value> 
        </element1> 
    </name> 
</names>
```

If you want all 'name' nodes with a time of 555555 then you'll need

```
//name[@time = '555555']
```

If you want all value nodes underneath name with a time of 555555 then you'll need

```
//name[@time = '555555']/element1/value
```

Comment: //name[@time = '555555'] ...using this I get boolean vaue of true.

Comment: +1 for somehow managing to meet the OP's need, despite the static.

Comment: @LarsH: I don't think we should encourage the same answer to the same question...

Comment: @Alej: point taken. The OP seemed to be arguing that it wasn't a duplicate if we "read both questions properly", and I didn't take the time to read them both carefully.